# How to use case function in SQL where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am converting a Crystal Report to SSRS.  In the CR Select Records section there are several filters including an IF statement like this:

```
(if BeginCompany <> 0 and EndCompany <> 999 then
     Company between BeginCompany and EndCompany else 1 = 1)
```

How can I make an equivalent CASE statement in an SQL WHERE clause in my dataset?  Thanks.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: So if BeginCompany is a "valid value" and EndCompany is 999, you just ignore both?

Answer (score 0):

Are `BeginCompany` and `EndCompany` actually variables? What are they when you don't want to use them as a filter? NULL? Something else?

Maybe you're looking for this (assuming companies are represented by positive integers):

```
WHERE Company >= COALESCE(@BeginCompany, 0)
  AND Company <= COALESCE(@EndCompany, 2147483647)
```

Which is just another way to express:

```
WHERE Company >= CASE 
      WHEN @BeginCompany IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @BeginCompany END
  AND Company <= CASE
      WHEN @EndCompany IS NULL THEN 2147483647 ELSE @EndCompany END
```

You *can't* use a `CASE` expression for control-of-flow, e.g.

```
CASE ... something ... THEN Column BETWEEN x AND y
```

`CASE` is an expression that *returns a single value*. Much more background here:

- [Dirty Secrets of the CASE Expression](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the logic wants the Company field to be between the BeginCompany and EndCompany parameters if BeginCompany <> 0 and EndCompany <> 999 to show a record but if they do equal 0 or 999, then show all records. If a users enters 0 for the Begin parameter or 999 for the end, then the query would show all records.

I think in SQL it would be

```
WHERE   (
        @BeginCompany <> 0 
        and @EndCompany <> 999 
        AND Company between @BeginCompany and @EndCompany
        )
    OR  (
        @BeginCompany = 0 
        OR
        @EndCompany = 999
        )
```

If you really wanted to squeeze a CASE statement if there then

```
WHERE CASE WHEN 
                @BeginCompany <> 0 
                and @EndCompany <> 999 
                AND Company between @BeginCompany and @EndCompany
            THEN 1
            WHEN 
                @BeginCompany = 0 
                OR
                @EndCompany = 999
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.